# Remote Desktop Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, vps, remote-desktop

I just ordered a VPS, running Windows Server. The only thing that this server needs to do is run a Powershell Script, which has an infinite loop (`while($true)`) with some code in it.

In general, if I connect to the VPS via Remote Desktop, everything is working fine, it runs and runs and runs. But whenever I quit Remote Desktop, the Powershell Script is paused and doesn't continue until I connect again.

Is there any way to make the script "permanent", so it doesn't halt when I quit the Remote Desktop session?

This is the Powershell-Script:

```
while($true)
{
Start-Sleep 2
start chrome.exe
Start-Sleep 2
Invoke-Item C:\Users\me\index.html
Start-Sleep 2
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}") 
Start-Sleep 1000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{F4}") 
Start-Sleep 2
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("%{F4}") 
}
```

By the way, I start the script from Powershell ISE, not directly execute the script, because then it doesn't know the context SendKeys somehow, but I think that shouldn't change anything, does it?

Comment: Ca you share the sample code?

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh did it

Comment: Could this be ran as a scheduled task possibly? That way it doesn't require a user to login and start the script.

Comment: How could I be able to do this?

Comment: problem is, that I can't run it as powershell script directly, but with ISE..., or do you have an idea how to change the `SendWait` commands to sth. else?

Comment: Figure out how to get the `SendWait` to be recognized in a script..my apologies that I can't be of more help

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell does not pause in disconnected sessions, but `SendKeys` does not work in disconnected sessions. This is an expected behaviour.

Comment: But it seems that it gets completely paused, so its not doing anything at all (besides the keystrokes), will the script completely stop then, when `SendKeys`-Commands are in then?
Could I somehow replace them, with something that continues working? or is there a way to press "Enter" in Chrome to confirm a alert dialog instead of simulating a keystroke?